# logitr with choice experiment data

Tags: multinomial

I am new in using the logitr package so I feel a bit out of the space. I have unlabeled choice experiment data. I have 5 alternatives where the 5th one is a no buy option. Do you have any idea about how should I treat this alternative? Of course that for alternative 5 all the attributes are coded as 0, also price. The problem is that the outcome I receive doesnt give any significance for any of the levels of the attributes but this is not in line with results I receive from other packages.

Thank you very much!

The price attribute is continues while the rest of the levels of the attributes are dummy variables, 1 when they appear in the alternative and 0 otherwise.